# CAML to search column name

Tags: caml-query, web, web-services

I'm looking to search within each list for a column.  The problem is that this column is referred to differently in CAML.  Look at this for a detailed explanation:
[Finding the internal name and display name for a list column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/787/finding-the-internal-name-and-display-name-for-a-list-column)

I'd like to know if there is a way to search the column name in CAML.  I've been reading over here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms467521.aspx and it seems as if you can only use  or  to search the values within the column itself.  Is there a way of doing this using CAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that you can do it with CAML, but you should be able to use the Lists web service to get a list of all columns for a list. What's the application here?

Comment: I'm making this recursive deletion a bit more flexible.  Possibly a template.  Your question just made me look at what I was doing and I think I got it now.  Silly me, I was using GetListItems instead of GetList.  

That should be all it takes.

Comment: Roger; I wasn't sure if you were trying to do some wacky complex query or something ;-)