# Get the DisplayName of the field from the List

Tags: 2007, development

Depends on the view I need to get the column name from the list.With the help of viewID I am able to retrieve the selected column from the list but I have an issue while retrieving the column names,I have written the code like this.

```
SPView currentlistview = currentList.GetView(viewID);


  foreach (string viewField in currentlistview.ViewFields)
  {
     string colname = currentList.Fields.GetField(viewField).Title;
     string colTitle = currentList.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(viewField);
  }
```

I have tried both the possibilities but I am getting the internal name of the field in the list.Could anyone provide a solution to get the display name of the field ?

Comment: SPField.Title is the display name. Have you created strange names for the columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should check this post

[Finding the internal name and display name for a list column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/787/finding-the-internal-name-and-display-name-for-a-list-column)

Hope it helps