# Different column name for SharePoint Webparts

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I'm trying to create a dashboard in SharePoint Designer 2010, however I'm getting two different column name.

1st Option: insert -> Data View -> Empty Data View -> select my List

[image]

2nd Option: insert -> Data View -> Select my list

[image]

What I want is to use the 1st option but to show the real column names that is visible in option 2.

Appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are getting the internal name of the column, use the display name of the column instead

you should check this post

[Finding the internal name and display name for a list column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/787/finding-the-internal-name-and-display-name-for-a-list-column)

Hope it helps