# Column 'Title' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user. /Global desktops

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, clients.svc

I'm getting this error

> Column 'Title' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user. /Global desktop

while clicking `Share files` button in ribbon. The information I got is as below:

- The request is going from Sharepoint js libraries to `http://site/_vti_bin/client.svc/ProcessQuery`
- I went in depth of REST query and resent after editing. I removed Title property from following query and it worked:

  `<Query Id="245" ObjectPathId="238"><Query SelectAllProperties="false"><Properties><Property Name="ID" SelectAll="true" /><Property Name="FileRef" SelectAll="true" /><Property Name="FileLeafRef" SelectAll="true" /><Property Name="Title" SelectAll="true" /></Properties></Query>`
- The result of the modified query is as follows:

> ```
>  245,
>    {
>     "_ObjectType_": "SP.ListItem",
>     "_ObjectIdentity_": "740c6a0b-85e2-48a0-a494-e0f1759d4aa7:site:8a58da05-7bef-4d82-84f2-a2a2e218af9b:web:ac1a65ba-a71e-4096-b939-7d880ad47b20:list:48eb9616-5dce-43af-8bb8-fa1b84bc3ebf:item:1,1",
>     "_ObjectVersion_": "3",
>     "ID": 1,
>     "FileRef": "/Global desktops/Testing.aspx",
>     "FileLeafRef": "Testing.aspx"
>   },
> ```

I am looking for a way to add a property `Title` to this `SP.ListItem` so that the error should not occur. Powershell solution would be preferred (for testing)

Answer (score 5):

you should use internal name.(below is the image to find internal name of column) :-
go to list setting -> Click on column name [Column (click to edit)] -> then you will see below image

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This really help me. We should use 'internal name' instead 'display name'. Now, I can execute my Power Shell script. :)

Answer (score 2):

The Title column can't be deleted or changed its data type, but it can be renamed or hide So,

- Make sure it's not renamed or hide .
- Make sure you have the correct `Internal Name` for the Field with the DisplayName `Title`.

**Note :** you may have a Linkable Title column with display name title but it's `internal name` is `LinkNoTitleMenu`

To get the internal name of specific field :

- browsing to the `List Settings > Edit Column` and look at the `Field` QueryString.

> /_layouts/15/FldEdit.aspx?List=%7B26D73055%2D4A4F%2D497B&`Field`=PercentComplete

**Note :** If you have space in your display name it's converted to '`_x0020_`' , '`_`' is converted to '`%5f`'

Check Also [Finding the internal name and display name for a list column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/787/finding-the-internal-name-and-display-name-for-a-list-column)

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with sharepoint document libraries remember that it uses the field name instead of title. If you look in a document lobrary the field title is most of time blank. Have you tried your query using name field?