# how to create new event in SharePoint calendar list with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-addin

i want to create new event in SharePoint calendar list in which I have some custom columns,i tried below code but it is not working

```
    function bookingRoomForMeeting() {
        var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(appWebUrl);//Get the SharePoint Context object based upon the URL  
        var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("MyCalendarList"); //Get the List based upon the Title
        var listCreationInformation = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation(); //Object for creating Item in the List
        listItem = list.addItem(listCreationInformation);
        listItem.set_item('Title', $("#txt_Title").val());
        var date = $("#txt_startTime").val();
        var dateTime = moment(date, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm a').format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm a");
        listItem.set_item('EventDate', dateTime);
        var enddate = $("#txt_endTime").val();
        var enddateTime = moment(enddate, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm a').format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm a");
        listItem.set_item('EndDate', enddateTime);
        listItem.set_item('EmailId1', $("#txt_EmailId1").val());
        listItem.set_item('EmailId2', $("#txt_EmailId2").val());
        listItem.update();
        ctx.load(listItem);
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.createDelegate(this, success),
            Function.createDelegate(this, fail)
           );
    }
function success() {
    alert("Completed");
}
function fail() {
    alert("operation failed");
}
```

list am using is SharePoint hosted app list,can any one tell me where am going wrong?

Comment: What error are you getting? Also make sure to use internal field names.

Comment: it is eexecuting fail() function

Comment: That is obvious. Update your fail function to get the error details. something like this `function fail(sender, args) {
        alert("Failed. Message:" + args.get_message());
    }`

Comment: 'Start Time' does not exist it may have been deleted by another user this is the error, Start Time is column name

Comment: As mentioned in my first comment, you need to use internal names of the fields not the display name.

Comment: okk,can you tell me the date time format for this?means if i want to enter data using text boxes then what format it should followed?

Comment: because am entering data into this(8/23/2016 12:00:00 PM) format and am getting string was not recognised as valit DateTime error

Comment: you need to convert the string to JavaScript date object before assigning it to the field.

Comment: can you suggest something?because i tried this conversion aproach but that also not working for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure to use internal names of the fields rather than the display name. Change `Start Time` to `EventDate` and `End Time` to `EndDate`. See
[Finding the internal name and display name for a list column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/787/finding-the-internal-name-and-display-name-for-a-list-column) for more information on internal field names.

Comment: the answer helped me to create event in SharePoint calendar list but it is taking and saves default servers time rather am passing,means suppose am passing 08/26/2016 12:00 an am expecting the same to got added in list but it saves default time instead of 12:00,so do you have any idea regarding this?

Comment: @Ma6139735, you should ask a new question for this. Include your code in the question.

Comment: yes i did that,http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/191877/custom-time-value-is-not-getting-saved-in-sharepoint-calendar-list-using-javascr