# How to save record(create new event) in sharepoint calendar list using javascript?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-calendar

i want to save data into sharepoint calendar list using javascript?i tried some thing but that is unable to save data into list [Link i followed](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/191295/how-to-create-new-event-in-sharepoint-calendar-list-with-javascript)

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/191295/how-to-create-new-event-in-sharepoint-calendar-list-with-javascript ,but the answer mensioned by you it is not up to date answer because that hasn't resolved  issue