# SPListItem will accept the column display name OR the column internal name

Tags: development, splistitem, splist

I am working on sharepoint server 2013. now i have the following column named "Date Reported", which have the following properties:-

- Display-Name = `Date Reported`
- Internal Name = `Date_x0020_Reported`

[image]

now i wrote the following code inside my console APP :-

```
 foreach (SPListItem item in testList.Items)
                            {

                                var test1 = item["Date_x0020_Reported"];
                                var test2 = item["Date Reported"];
```

and seems both variables `Test1` & `Test2` got the correct date value. which means i can reference the item field value either using the field display name Or the field internal name? is this the case? and if the answer is Yes then could this cause conflicts .. let say a field internal name equal another field display name ?

Thanks

Comment: Pretty good write-up on Internal name vs Display name by @MarcAnderson here..http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/787/finding-the-internal-name-and-display-name-for-a-list-column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**From MSDN**: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem

> For an indexer based on a name, Microsoft SharePoint Foundation first
>   looks for the field by internal name and then by display name.

**Conclusion**:

There was no conflict, except that in the same query you're using a mixture of internal names and display names.

**In general it is always advisable to use internal names.**

Answer (score 1):

Hi Prefer using internal name while query because when change the column name to something else then the query won't work by using display name.

Try querying record  by changing the column display name to something else.

Comment: but what will sharepoint expect Internal name or Display name ? or will accept both ?

Comment: It is advised to go with Internal name because you never who or when somebody has changed the Dispay Name of the given column.

Comment: i know it is better to use internal but my question is about how SP works will it looj for internal names or for display names?